# Resource to obtain listings of tissues that different viruses infect

Tags: database, virology

I am working on a project that involves analysis of viral DNA sequences. I'd like test hypotheses about issue specificity. Ideally I'd be able to get a table of virus/strain names with a column in it for something like 'tissue tropism' which would equal neurons/nervous system, liver, epithelia, etc etc. Does anybody where I could find this?

I so far haven't located it [www.viprbrc.org](http://www.viprbrc.org) which seems to be molecular bio info like domains, dna sequence etc.

I also found this paper [paper](https://bmcbiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12915-020-00785-5) which has data in the ideal format but is limited to analysis of RNAseq data and to healthy subjects.

Comment: I understand the question, for example HPV targets skin cells, HBV liver, however a lot have complex/cryptic lifecycles for example the different HHV. My view of this information/question is that it is a classic virology textbook rather than a singular database. DNA viruses are quite a specific group, which includes VZV (chicken pox virus HHV3) and smallpox BTW. They often form complex chronic infections (HPV many HHV) and thats not really database stuff. Transferring  this question to biology.stackexchange is probably the right place for it IMO.

Comment: Tried [viralzone](https://viralzone.expasy.org/)?

Comment: Animal viruses? Vertebrate viruses? Mammalian viruses? Human viruses? Please clarify.